# Creating an sf object from the maps package

Tags: r, ggplot2, sf

I am trying to use data from the `maps` package in an `sf` workflow. I'm not sure if I have the operation correct (see below). It seems to work until state 20 (massachusetts). What am I doing wrong? Maybe there is a better way to do this?

```
state_data <- ggplot2::map_data("state")
state_data_sf <- lapply(unique(state_data$region),
                function(x)
                  list(matrix(unlist(
                  state_data[state_data$region == x,][,c("long", "lat")]),
                  ncol = 2)))

sf::st_polygon(state_data_sf[[19]])
```

> POLYGON((-87.4620056152344 30.3896808624268, -87.4849319458008 39.6200332641602, -78.1113357543945 39.6658706665039, -78.1342544555664 39.67732...

sf::st_polygon(state_data_sf[[20]])

> Error in MtrxSet(x, dim, type = "POLYGON", needClosed = TRUE) : 
>     polygons not (all) closed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out. The polygons need to be manually closed by rbinding the first row:

```
state_data <- ggplot2::map_data("state")
state_data_sf <- lapply(unique(state_data$region),
                function(x)
                  list(matrix(unlist(
                  rbind(
                    state_data[state_data$region == x,][,c("long", "lat")],
                    state_data[state_data$region == x,][1, c("long", "lat")])),
                  ncol = 2)))
res <- lapply(state_data_sf, sf::st_polygon)
```

**EDIT**

This is a much better solution. It is cleaner and does not suffer from closed polygon issues.

```
states <- sf::st_as_sf(maps::map("state", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))
```

Comment: Used this resource to answer: https://eriqande.github.io/rep-res-web/lectures/making-maps-with-R.html

Comment: `st_as_sf` works well. I'm wondering, however, why is `fill=TRUE` necessary?