# Raster of missing values inside polygon in R

Tags: raster, r

I have a raster `r`representing values from 0 to 50 for the world. There are large areas with missing values `NA` values, including:

- All oceans
- Large **inland regions** such as deserts

The problem is that when I plot `r` all NAs appear with the same colour regardless of whether they are oceans or deserts. This does not look nice, so I want to **display inland NAs in a different colour** than oceans.

I was thinking perhaps I could grab a map representing continents (e.g. `map("world")`), and create a layer of all NAs in `r` that fall inside continents. Then, I can just overlap this new raster on top of `r` in a different colour.

How can I create a new raster with all the inland missing values in a raster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you haven't provided any datasets to start with I have made some reproducible ones:

Firstly, here is a [random raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17255/random-sampling-of-raster-using-r). Missing values are inserted fo 70% of the cells:

```
library(raster)
rast <- raster(ncol=100, nrow=100, xmn=-130, xmx=-70, ymn=0, ymx=60)
rast[] <- 1:(100*100)
rast[runif(100*100) >= 0.30] <- NA
```

Next, I will load the US boundaries from [mapdata](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230608/creating-an-sf-object-from-the-maps-package). I used the package `sf` to create the polygons, but sadly these are not compatible with rasters yet, so I converted it back to a spatial polygon at the end:

```
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(mapdata)
states <- sf::st_as_sf(map("state", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))
states <-  as(states, 'Spatial')
```

Comparing these two shapefiles:

```
plot(states)
plot(rast, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

The easiest way of locating cells over land is to use the `mask` function. This only leaves cells which overlay the polygon provided. Before doing the mask though, I will set all NAs to a specified value, in this case -9999.

```
# Replace all NAs with a value
rast[is.na(rast)] <- -9999

overlay <- mask(rast, states)
```

[image]